# Can I pipe the pathname expansion to a command?

Tags: bash, pathname

Using bash I want to accomplish what the following command does without using the `ls` command and instead using pure pathname expansion. Is this possible?

```
ls * | tail -1
```

I'm looking for something like

```
* | tail -1
```

Comment: What is your goal? Is this just a theoretical question about syntax or do you have a concrete use case? `tail` expects something from stdin, so you need a program (such as `ls`)  write something to stdout, in order that you can pipe it into `tail`. This program does not need to be `ls`; you can also write your own.

Comment: @user1934428 my goal is to do the same as `ls * | tail -1` i.e. get the last filename that matches a given pattern. I'm creating a list of numbered files, so after file 001 I want to create file 002, etc... The first step is figuring out which is the highest existing number in the directory

Comment: If you want to achieve this result, than simply write it as such. If you get tired to type `ls`, make an alias or function to name it just `l` (one character less to type). BTW, you don't necessarily get the last filename with this, because if the filename contains a newline character, `ls` would split it into two lines. You are are safer assigning to an array first, i.e. `lsa=(*)` and then accessing the last array element.

Comment: One other note the result from `*` is unordered. The result from `ls -1` will be ordered based on the current sort rules for ls (which /may/ be unordered).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use do that, but `*` doesn't do what you think it does. It expands to a list of the directory contents and tries to execute itself as a binary. This can be dangerous when your directory contents contain actual executables that are not meant to be run.

You can use a shell built-in without forking a separate process, to do something with the pathname expansion result. For e.g. using `printf()`

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

See what happens when you just try to execute `*` in the commandline

```
mkdir -p foobar
cd foobar
touch zeezee
*
bash: zeezee: command not found
```

You can `tail` the result of this output and filter the results as you seem convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `*` expanded list to a function and output the last argument:

```
f() { printf "%s\n" "${@: -1}"; }; f *
```